# Outlook 2013 VSTO Addin - How to check if the Mail view is selected?

Tags: outlook, vsto

In an Outlook 2013 VSTO addin (C#), I can check to see if the user is currently in the Calendar area/view by using "if(ActiveExplorer().CurrentView is CalendarView) ..."

How do I do something similar to check and see if the user is in the Mail view, where "Mail" is selected/blue at the bottom of the Outlook window and the user sees their Inbox items?  There is no MailView type, or anything similar that I could find, to compare ActiveExplorer().CurrentView, etc., against.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `CurrentView` property of the Explorer class I'd suggest checking the [DefaultItemType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865360.aspx) property of the Folder class. It returns a constant from the OlItemType enumeration indicating the default Outlook item type contained in the folder.

The [CurrentFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff866719.aspx) property of the Folder class returns a Folder object that represents the current folder displayed in the explorer. So, the code may look like the following one:

```
 ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder.DefaultItemType
```